# Querying Count on Joined Table Not Displaying Result for Zero Count

Tags: mysql

I want to to return rows from a parent rows with a count of child rows relational to the parent ID. Unfortunately, I have run into an issue with my query where it will only return rows with child rows, those without child rows do not return results. I have tried LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER, and INNER joins to no avail. SQLFiddle link and query below:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(s.id) AS cnt FROM top AS t 
JOIN sub AS s ON t.id = s.top_id GROUP BY t.id, t.name 
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c466fe/1

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Changing your `JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` does the job for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c466fe/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem you need `LEFT JOIN`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c466fe/4

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.name, 
       COUNT(s.id) AS cnt 
FROM top AS t 
LEFT JOIN sub AS s 
ON t.id = s.top_id 
GROUP BY t.id, t.name 
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

Comment: It seems I did, I was using JOIN LEFT instead of LEFT JOIN. What a dummy...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(s.id) AS cnt 
FROM top AS t 
left JOIN sub AS s ON t.id = s.top_id GROUP BY t.id, t.name 
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```